# Excel- Merge cells with same text in one column and add time values in another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have first column containing values in text and a second one containing duration for each value.
I would like to merge two or more cells which has the same value in the first column and add the time values in the second column. How can I do this?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are cells in the first column with identical text next to each other, or do they need to be sorted?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily with a pivot table. Just select your data and click `Pivot Table` on the Insert ribbon.

[image]

After choosing a location for your pivot table (mine is at `D1` on the same sheet in this sample, but you may find it better to have it on a separate sheet), just drag and drop the fields from the Pivot Table Field List into the appropriate categories: `Event` will go under Row Values and `Duration` will go under Values. Since `Sum` is the default setting for pivot table values, this is all you need to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula `=SubTotal(9, DURATION_RANGE)` for **DURATION** range and filter out the required text value(s). the Subtotal will show the sum of all the duration values of the selected texts.